# LMFIT: ' ValueError: The input contains nan values'when Data Input is all Float

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I'm trying to Curve-Fit a data-set, that I got from and Integration, which lmfit says contains NaN value.

The same Data were fitted with scipy_curvefit, that was SUPER Bad.  I'm trying this library for some better results.

I tried to change my yData and xData to some simple arrays (you will see below) and got the same error!

```
from lmfit import Model
def poly(x, a1,a2,a3,a4,a5):
    return a1+a2*x**a3+a4*x**a5
x=s
y=vrr
x=[0.,1.,2.,3.,5.,6.]
y=[4.,5.,6.,12.,3.,5.]
gmodel = Model(poly)
gmodel_parameters= gmodel.make_params()
gmodel_parameters['a1'].set(value=10)
gmodel_parameters['a2'].set(value=10)
gmodel_parameters['a3'].set(value=7)
gmodel_parameters['a4'].set(value=10)
gmodel_parameters['a5'].set(value=7)
result=gmodel.fit(x=x,data=y,params=gmodel_parameters)

plt.plot(x, y, 'k--')
plt.plot(x, result.best_fit, 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I see you're assigning `s` and `vrr` values to `x` and `y`. Could you provide some information on these (I mean`s` and `vrr`)? Especially, what are the types, maybe some `print(s, vrr)`?

Comment: @pmarcol Ofc, although, note that I re-assigned x and y to simple arrays. 

`len(s),len(vrr),type(s),type(vrr)` give, respectively, `(12000, 12000, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray) ` and every element is Float (I have done Graphs with them, and they are a result of an integration, as noted in the post :) )

Comment: This looks to me that it is the initial parameter estimates. Without making any other change, try these values for initial parameter estimates: a1 =  3.5E+00, a2 = -8.5E+01, a3 =  1.5E+00, a4 =  8.7E+01, a5 =  1.5E+00

Comment: @JamesPhillips It was indeed model/parameter problem. Thing is, the fit is SUPER bad. It's as bad as the Curve_Fit :(  -as I posted below-

Comment: This does not appear to use the data in your code sample, would you please post the data you refer to?

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when you fit an exponent. If the program sets this variable to less than zero, you may have a NaN error. Read the documentation and try to add min=0 to a3 and a5 as a optimization option.

https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/model.html#the-model-class

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, you are right, I turned it into Polyonyman + Exponential but the fit is still total [trash](https://i.ibb.co/bmj7n5j/Screenshot-from-2019-05-29-15-13-33.png)!

Comment: Try to change the fitting tolerance or the minimization method. In https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/tutorial/optimize.html you can find different examples using optimize of scipy.